# Getting Excel column type as actual underlying value and not formatted value with C#

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Simple set up - I have an Excel file which has a column of doubles:

```
0.94
0.9523
0.9293
```

The Excel file has this column formatted to be a rounded percentage:

```
94%
95%
93%
```

In C#, where I set up an `OleDbConnection` to query this Excel file, all my values are returned as:

```
94%
95%
93%
```

but I need the *actual* and **unrounded** values.

My connection string includes the extended properties:

```
...Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=No;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text"
```

but this doesn't seem to do the trick. So my question is, ***short of changing the Excel document manually to the proper type*** how can I get this to return the data the way I need it?

I've heard and read about changing the registry, but this isn't the best option as this will be deployed on multiple machines. Is this the only way of doing what I need?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly do not want `ImportMixedTypes=Text`.

Try it with `TypeGuessRows=1;ImportMixedTypes=Majority Types`.